# Blocks besides each others

Tags: html, css

I have a given HTML which I can't touch:

```
<fieldset>
  <label for="username" class="text">
    Dein Benutzername<span class="req">*</span>
  </label>
  <div class="div_text">
    <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="" class="textbox" required="">
  </div>
  <label for="first_name" class="text">
    Vorname<span class="req">*</span>
  </label>
  <div class="div_text">
    <input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" value="" class="textbox" required="">
  </div>
  <label ....
```

and I need to output that one with 2 same-width columns where the label is above the corresponding div-block and the next input-div-block and their corresponding label is besides it.

I added an image to show exactly what I want it to be. I run into problems because the label-tag sits within the same hierarchy-level as the div-block and I therefore can't use inline-block nor - due to my lack of knwoledge - flexbox as it's a mix between column and row in flex-direction[image: desired output]

Could somebody please guide me on that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use flexbox and put the elements into a new order. It is not a elegant way but the only solution i can
think of if you cant touch the HTML

```css
.text,
.div_text {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
}
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
label[for=username] {
  order: 1;;
}
label[for=first_name] {
  order: 2;
}
fieldset div:nth-of-type(1){
  order: 3;      
}
fieldset div:nth-of-type(2){
  order: 4;
}
label[for=sur_name] {
  order: 5;
}
label[for=example] {
  order: 6;
}
fieldset div:nth-of-type(3){
  order: 7;
}
fieldset div:nth-of-type(4){
  order: 8;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <label for="username" class="text">Dein Benutzername<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div class="div_text">
    <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="" class="textbox" required="">
  </div>
  <label for="first_name" class="text">Vorname<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div class="div_text">
    <input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" value="" class="textbox" required="">
  </div>
  <label for="sur_name" class="text">Nachname<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div class="div_text">
    <input name="sur_name" type="text" id="sur_name" value="" class="textbox" required="">
  </div>
  <label for="example" class="text">Weiters Beispiel<span class="req">*</span></label>
  <div class="div_text">
    <input name="example" type="text" id="example" value="" class="textbox" required="">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. But does that really work out for you? I tried https://codepen.io/daiaiai/pen/JmEqZG and seems to me nothing works there. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: The code seems to work on firefox and safari. Did you use chrome?

Comment: yep. Do I need to prefix something on Chrome? Really?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know why it's not working in chrome. I tried to look it up in web but couldnt find the solution. I will continue searching later :(

Answer (score 0):

Hoping you are not using any css framework, please have a look at the below-working snippet with custom markup and css, hope it helps :)

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
fieldset {
  clear: both;
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px dashed deeppink;
}
legend {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: deeppink;
  margin: 0 0 10px 15px;
}
.form-group {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 2.5%;
}
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Fieldset Container</legend>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="labelX">Label x</label>
    <input id="labelX" type="text" placeholder="Label X" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="labelY">Label y</label>
    <input id="labelY" type="text" placeholder="Label Y" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="labelZ">Label z</label>
    <input id="labelZ" type="text" placeholder="Label Z" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="labelXX">Label xx</label>
    <input id="labelXX" type="text" placeholder="Label XX" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```